# i18next.changeLanguage not propagating to child-webcomponents

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, web-component, i18next, react-i18next

Our monorepo-project has the following structure (roughly):

```
├── commons       # provides i18n-instance
├── orchestrator  # is wrapped with <I18nextProvider/>, encapsulates <component1/> and <component2/>
├── component1    # is wrapped with <I18nextProvider>
└── component2    # is wrapped with <I18nextProvider>
```

`orchestrator`, `component1` and `component2` are all written in React and compile to webcomponents, where `component1` and `component2` are children of `orchestrator`.

I wrap all webcomponents with `<I18NextProvider>`, passing them all **the same i18next-instance, that is provided by the `commons`-workspace**.

When I now call `i18n.changeLanguage("en")` from within the `orchestrator`, the changes don't propagate to `component1` and `component2`. Not even, if I rerender the whole app after changing the language.

Do I have to provide three separate i18next-instances and call `changeLanguage` on all of them separately? Is there a way I can keep working with a single instance and call `changeLanguage` a single time?